# Corrupted resultset using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

Python version 2.6
pyodbc version 3.0.6

Python code example:
    #!/usr/bin/python26

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys

SQL = sys.argv[1];

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=VerticaDSN')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(SQL)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print row[0]
```

Instead of printing data as is in the table, python outputs corrupted data, only part of data, like

```
ps
t Foods
smart
ly Dollar
enney
ean
rd
```

Expected resultset:

```
Ames
Ukrops
Giant Foods
Cardsmart
Aco
Family Dollar
JC Penney
Eckerd
```

Why Resultset gets corrupted?
Any suggestions?

Comment: What DBMS for the data source (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc) and what driver in use?

Comment: Vertica. 
Driver libverticaodbc.so

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely is not in `pyodbc` but in ODBC driver itself. Here is several things to try:

- Try to cast column into another data type (not sure what database you are using, but it is possible that column is in Unicode, and driver understands only ASCII, or other way around; I'm inclined to think that this is the problem)
- use specialized python client for your database if available instead of ODBC (like `cx_Oracle`, `psycopg2`)
- look at ODBC driver configuration parameters
- install ODBC driver from a different vendor

Comment: Cast did not help.  So far I found only one client, pyvertica, to work with Vertica. But it does not suit me.

Comment: Why it does not suit you? `pyvertica` claims to be `psycopg2` clone. You may try to use original `psycopg2` (it worked for me to connect to Greenplum database from both Windows and Solaris clients); BTW: type casting trick worked for me when I tried to read exotic 'name' datatype from Netezza database through ODBC, which is why I recommended trying it.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will try psycopg2. But for connection it is using pyodbc, isn't it? If so the issue remains.

Comment: NO! `pyodbc` is used only with ODBC drivers like this: python talks to `pyodbc`, `pyodbc` converts python datatypes/calls to C datatypes/calls and talks to ODBC *driver* (implemented in C), ODBC driver talks to database. With psycopg2: psycopg2 is build (linked) with PostgreSQL frontend libraries (statically or dynamically) so it talks to database using same libraries as `psql` does. It is native and uses different implementation. It may require psql libraries (http://sourceforge.net/projects/psql/) to be installed (but not psql itself!). (BTW: cx_Oracle requires Oracle instant client)

Comment: Also: I'm not familiar with `pyvertica`, but it may require additional binaries (like PostgreSQL frontend) to be installed